# Same dockerfile built on two different machines. One builds correctly and runs, the other gets an error installing a python package using pip

Tags: python, linux, docker

I'm having trouble building a docker file on  my machines, but it build correctly on another machine.

Here's the DockerFile:

FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0-gpu-jupyter

```
RUN apt-get update && \ 
apt-get install -y ffmpeg && \ 
pip install pyroomacoustics
```

On one machine it builds correctly with no errors but on my computer I get an error during a pip install of pyroomacoustics. I also tried this on my macbook and it failed with the same error.Two other people ran it for me on their machines and it worked for them fine. Im confused why this would occur.

Here's the error:

```
from pyroomacoustics) (1.18.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyroomacoustics
  Building wheel for pyroomacoustics (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for pyroomacoustics (PEP 517): still running...
  Building wheel for pyroomacoustics (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmprd5bmv1v
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m7cvkov3/pyroomacoustics
  Complete output (119 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/recognition.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/utilities.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/metrics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/soundsource.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/beamforming.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/multirate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/room.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/parameters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/sync.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  copying pyroomacoustics/acoustics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/grid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/frida.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/doa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/waves.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/srp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/tops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/detect_peaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/music.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/tools_fri_doa_plane.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/plotters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  copying pyroomacoustics/doa/cssm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/doa
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/rls.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/adaptive_filter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/subband_lms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/data_structures.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  copying pyroomacoustics/adaptive/lms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/adaptive
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/transform
  copying pyroomacoustics/transform/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/transform
  copying pyroomacoustics/transform/stft.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/transform
  copying pyroomacoustics/transform/dft.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/transform
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/delay_calibration.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/physics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/deconvolution.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/measure_ir.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/localization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/point_cloud.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/rt60.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  copying pyroomacoustics/experimental/signals.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/experimental
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  copying pyroomacoustics/datasets/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  copying pyroomacoustics/datasets/cmu_arctic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  copying pyroomacoustics/datasets/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  copying pyroomacoustics/datasets/timit.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  copying pyroomacoustics/datasets/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  copying pyroomacoustics/datasets/google_speech_commands.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/datasets
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/ilrma.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/auxiva.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/trinicon.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/fastmnmf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/sparseauxiva.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  copying pyroomacoustics/bss/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/bss
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/denoise
  copying pyroomacoustics/denoise/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/denoise
  copying pyroomacoustics/denoise/spectral_subtraction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/denoise
  copying pyroomacoustics/denoise/subspace.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/denoise
  copying pyroomacoustics/denoise/iterative_wiener.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/denoise
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/phase
  copying pyroomacoustics/phase/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/phase
  copying pyroomacoustics/phase/gl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/phase
  copying pyroomacoustics/build_rir.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/data
  copying pyroomacoustics/data/materials.json -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/data
  running build_ext
  creating tmp
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c /tmp/tmpob74w7b2.cpp -o tmp/tmpob74w7b2.o -std=c++14
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c /tmp/tmphu4obqnd.cpp -o tmp/tmphu4obqnd.o -fvisibility=hidden
  cythoning pyroomacoustics/build_rir.pyx to pyroomacoustics/build_rir.c
  building 'pyroomacoustics.libroom' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/libroom_src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -Ipyroomacoustics/libroom_src -I/tmp/pip-build-env-dghh1s3w/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-dghh1s3w/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybind11/include -Ipyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/libroom.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/libroom.o -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY -Wall -O3 -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG -DVERSION_INFO="0.4.1" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  In file included from pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/Core:450:0,
                   from /tmp/pip-build-env-dghh1s3w/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/eigen.h:36,
                   from pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/libroom.cpp:30:
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h: In member function ‘std::tuple<Eigen::Matrix<float, D, 1, (AutoAlign | (((((int)D) == 1) && (1 != 1)) ? RowMajor : (((1 == 1) && (((int)D) != 1)) ? ColMajor :  ColMajor))), D, 1>, int, float> Room<D>::next_wall_hit(Vectorf<D>&, Vectorf<D>&, bool) [with long unsigned int D = 2]’:
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:194:66: warning: ‘result’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       DenseStorage(const DenseStorage& other) : m_data(other.m_data) {
                                                                    ^
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:194:66: warning: ‘*((void*)& result +4)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h: In member function ‘std::tuple<Eigen::Matrix<float, D, 1, (AutoAlign | (((((int)D) == 1) && (1 != 1)) ? RowMajor : (((1 == 1) && (((int)D) != 1)) ? ColMajor :  ColMajor))), D, 1>, int, float> Room<D>::next_wall_hit(Vectorf<D>&, Vectorf<D>&, bool) [with long unsigned int D = 3]’:
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:194:66: warning: ‘result’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       DenseStorage(const DenseStorage& other) : m_data(other.m_data) {
                                                                    ^
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:194:66: warning: ‘*((void*)& result +4)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/ext/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:194:66: warning: ‘*((void*)& result +8)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  In file included from pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/room.hpp:254:0,
                   from pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/libroom.cpp:38:
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/room.cpp: In member function ‘bool Room<D>::is_visible_dfs(Vectorf<D>&, ImageSource<D>&) [with long unsigned int D = 2]’:
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/room.cpp:374:18: warning: ‘*((void*)& intersection +4)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         Vectorf<D> intersection;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  pyroomacoustics/libroom_src/room.cpp:374:18: warning: ‘intersection’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
  /tmp/pip-build-env-dghh1s3w/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /tmp/pip-install-m7cvkov3/pyroomacoustics/pyroomacoustics/build_rir.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyroomacoustics
Failed to build pyroomacoustics
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyroomacoustics which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Does anyone know the reason why this would occur? Since they're being built with the same Dockerfile, I would assume that if it works on one machine it would work on every other machine.

Comment: from the output, one of your computers is running out of memory while building the image

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before, when an intermediary image was already downloaded on one machine with an older version. You can try removing all docker images and rebuilding cleanly again. Try `docker system prune`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried docker system prune -a already and no luck. Thank you for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the above comment by Anthony Sottile, it was a memory issue. I increased the memory limit in the docker settings and it worked.